# K-means clustering is not grouping around the centroid

Tags: python, pandas, k-means

I am fairly new to ML and pandas/scipy, so please bear with me. I am trying to run K-means clustering using sklearn.cluster KMEANS module and I am not getting the expected results from my clustering.

The data set I am working with is a 64 by 6830 matrix of genomic data. The rows being a particular cancer cell line and the columns being the expression values.

I standardized the data so that the standard deviation is 1 and the mean is 0.

In a `dataframe`, the data looks like this:

```
                  0         1         2         3         4         5     \
Cancer Types                                                               
CNS           0.728671  1.607220  1.325688  1.355688 -0.604845 -0.220654   
CNS           1.596418  1.753544  0.441686  0.654119  0.911898  1.648748   
CNS           2.190290 -0.016217 -0.349092  0.266465 -1.311310 -0.019322   
RENAL         0.682995 -0.375502  1.628079 -0.444299  1.244434 -0.019322   
BREAST        1.151170 -0.581759  0.965145  1.138767  0.361351 -0.033703   
...                ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...   
MELANOMA     -0.024977 -0.601719  0.209168 -0.342761 -0.459396  1.159911   
MELANOMA     -0.573084  0.875343 -0.186266  1.318766  2.117127  0.210772   
MELANOMA      0.523130 -0.788015 -0.302571 -0.924296  0.039286 -1.169792   
MELANOMA     -0.070652  0.223307 -0.163005 -0.859681  0.039286 -0.019322   
MELANOMA      0.842860 -0.322275  0.092864 -0.831988 -1.539873 -0.997222
```

Here is the python code that I am using the create the KMEANS clustering

```
vals = standardize.values

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=4, n_init=150, random_state=123)
km.fit(vals)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(14,5))

ax.scatter(vals[:,0], vals[:,1], c = km.labels_, cmap=plt.cm.plasma_r) 
ax.set_title('K-Means Clustering Results with K=4')
ax.scatter(km.cluster_centers_[:,0], km.cluster_centers_[:,1], marker='+', s=100, c='k', linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

And here are my results:
[image]

As you can see none of my plot points are clustered correctly around the centroids

Comment: Your training data has 6 features, you're only plotting the first two. To plot a 6 dimensional space like this, you have to reduce the dimensions to 2.

Comment: Hi Michael, Any Idea how I would go about reducing the dimension down to 2 without just using the first two features to create the KMEANS clustures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are representing only 2 columns of your data, while clustering was done in the original space 64 * 6830.

So each one of the centroids should be a vector of 6830 dimension, but you are using only 2 dimensions (genes in your case) in the plot.

To plot your data I would suggest you to use something like PCA, or UMAP to project your data in a 2D space that can be easily represented, than apply k-means. In this way your centroid will have only 2 dimension that you can easily plot and also your samples will be represented by 2 coordinates.

Furthermore, clustering in high dimensional space is complicate especially using a metric like the Euclidean distance. So, down projecting your data in a lower dimensional space should help even the clustering and not only be good for the representation.
Using PCA you can down project the data in 2D in the following way.
Other non linear models may be projecting the data even better.

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = vals
Transformed_x = PCA(2).fit_transform(X)
```

Than apply k-means as you did

Comment: Thank you, PCA dimensionality reduction was exactly what I needed/wanted in my case.